# POST file binary data stream to HTTPS request in NodeJS (without Express)

Tags: node.js, https, stream, github-api

I am trying to upload a file (.exe installer) to a GitHub release via a NodeJS script using the [GitHub Releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset). The doc says my file must be sent in raw binary form in the POST request's body. My installer is over 30 MB, so I assumed I had to stream it.

**I cannot use external NPM dependencies such as Express or Request**, so I am trying to do this with just the built-in HTTPS module. I am struggling to get that to work.

Here's what I am trying:

```
// (URL below has proper values in my code)
var fullUploadUrl = url.parse("https://uploads.github.com/repos/[org]/[repo]/releases/[release id]/assets?name=myFile.exe&access_token=[GitHub access token]");
var uploadRequest = https.request({
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" },
    method: "POST",
    protocol: "https:",
    hostname: fullUploadUrl.hostname,
    path: fullUploadUrl.path
}, (res) => {
    if (res.statusCode !== 201) {
        // Error
    } else {
        // Success
    }
});

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(uploadAssetPath);    
// readStream.on("end", () => {        // I have also tried with this uncommented
//    uploadRequest.end();
// });
readStream.pipe(uploadRequest);
```

This results in an immediate 400 status code.

What is the proper way to stream binary data to an HTTPS POST request? Does anyone have an example of how to programmatically upload large assets to a GitHub release in a NodeJS environment without external NPM dependencies?

**EDIT:** We ended up using the external `request` module, so please be aware that the accepted answer does not reflect the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using an external module would be fine. I use [request](https://github.com/request/request#forms) to stream data to another server. Have a look at this snippet:

```
var r = request.post('http://service.com/upload', function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {...})
var form = r.form();
form.append('my_field', 'my_value');
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer([1, 2, 3]));
form.append('custom_file', fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/unicycle.jpg'), {filename: 'unicycle.jpg'});
```

Comment: We would prefer not to bring an entire new dependency just for this, our project is already huge. The NodeJS doc specifically says: `http.request() returns an instance of the http.ClientRequest class. The ClientRequest instance is a writable stream. If one needs to upload a file with a POST request, then write to the ClientRequest object.` So, there has to be a way of doing this with just the built-in modules

Comment: Actually, after some frustration we gave up and decided to use the `request` module. I'll accept your answer because that's what we ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `:` is causing your 400 [Bad request] http response in `protocol: "https:"`.

Comment: I get `Protocol "https" not supported. Expected "https:"` when trying to remove the colon, so I guess it has to stay there